# Django Views append a variable to the .save variable?

Tags: python, django

I have this view where I get two different variables with data,

```
formulario = adendum_Form(request.POST)
nombreMedicci = request.POST.get('e2_2')
```

But I need to save the data from the two variables in formulario, how can I append the nombreMedicci to fomulario? I tried with

```
formulario.append(nombreMedicci)
```

but I get and error, this is my view.

view.py

```
@login_required(login_url='/InicieSesion')
def adendum_View(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formulario = adendum_Form(request.POST)
        nombreMedicci = request.POST.get('e2_2')
        formulario.append(nombreMedicci)
       if formulario.is_valid():
            formulario.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Alta Exitosa!')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('')
       else:
           messages.success(request, 'Se presento un error al dar de alta')
   else:
      elementos=Medico.objects.values('id', 'ap_paterno', 'nombre').order_by('ap_paterno')
      formulario = adendum_Form()
     return render_to_response('adendum.html', {'formulario': formulario,'elementos':elementos}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Is `adendum_Form` a ModelForm? Do you have a `Formulario` model? If so, what does it look like?